# dplyr: filter a value by existing in two conditions

Tags: r, dplyr

I've got a dataframe that currently looks like this

```
class   name   age
first   John   38
coach   Mark   34
coach   Jane   45
coach   John   56
```

I'd like to grab any name that exists in both types of 'class'. In this case that'd be John for having that name exist in both coach and first class.

I thought this might work, but it doesn't

```
df %>% group_by(name) %>% filter(n()>1) %>% filter(class == 'first' & class == 'coach')
```

Thanks

Comment: `Reduce(intersect, split(df$name, df$class))`

Comment: Well what did you expect? Let's break this down: Only `"John"` has `>1` rows. But you're checking for `class == "first"` **and** `class == "coach"` (i.e. logical AND). Did you mean `class == "first" | class == "coach"` (i.e. logical OR)?

Comment: @RonakShah I don't think this is a dupe of the question you flagged. I think OP is confusing logical AND and OR (see my comment).

Comment: @MauritsEvers I think it is. OP is trying to find a `name` which is common in all the `class` which the flagged question answers. As far as the confusion is considered that is what OP has tried and thought that it could solve the question.

Comment: Thanks, Ronak. I tried searching and didn't come across this, but your answer works to solve my problem. Thanks!

Comment: @MauritsEvers, I wasn't confused about and/or, I want both class conditions to be true, so **and** is what I wanted

Comment: @EricVaughn No worries, glad your issue got resolved.